# Find percentage for each item on each date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given Table:

```
Date            Item    Sales
-----------------------
2021-01-01       A      2000
2021-01-01       B      3000
2021-01-01       C      5000
2021-01-02       A      5000
2021-01-02       B      8000
2021-01-02       C      7000
```

The question is to find the respective percentage of sales for each item to the daily total. Like percentage of sales of item 'A' to total sales of '2021-01-01'.

I need output as the below table:

```
Date          Item    Sales   Percent
-------------------------------------
2021-01-01     A      2000     20
2021-01-01     B      3000     30
2021-01-01     C      5000     50
2021-01-02     A      5000     25
2021-01-02     B      8000     40
2021-01-02     C      7000     35
```

Please help me in this question. I have issue in query formation. Please provide suggestions for MS - SQL.

Comment: If you want SQLServer help DONT TAG MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sum` window function:

```
select 
  *, 
  100.0 * sum(Sales) over(partition by Date, Item) / sum(Sales) over(partition by date) as "Percent" 
from 
  table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a78d59e582e9f85b4fc50ac02f9bf8a)

Answer (score 1):

*join table* with *itself* in *subquery* as follows and use *cast* for *numerator* as follows

```
SELECT a.date,
       item,
       sales,
       Cast(sales AS FLOAT) * 100 / salessum AS percentage
FROM   sales a
       JOIN (SELECT Sum(sales) salessum,
                    date
             FROM   sales a
             GROUP  BY date) b
         ON a.date = b.date
```

or use *window function* form of *sum* as follows

```
SELECT
    Date,Item,Sales,
    100 * Sales / SUM(Sales) OVER (partition by date ) AS Percentage
FROM Sales  a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The query with window function is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using the window function `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` is the most concise method here.
NB I have renamed the column ***date*** to ***Date_sold***. The use of function names and keywords for naming tables, columns or variables can lead to errors or unexpected results.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   Date_sold,
>   Item,
>   sales,
>   100 * Sales / SUM(Sales) OVER
>         (PARTITION BY Date_sold) 
>         AS "Percent"
> FROM
>   sales;
> ```
>
> ```
> Date_sold  | Item | sales | Percent
> :--------- | :--- | ----: | ------:
> 2021-01-01 | A    |  2000 |      20
> 2021-01-01 | B    |  3000 |      30
> 2021-01-01 | A    |  5000 |      50
> 2021-01-02 | B    |  8000 |      53
> 2021-01-02 | C    |  7000 |      46
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48f5596f13205ed101a240fd688f6072)*